# Konsole Message after upgrade: cannot find -lcr

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, kubuntu, konsole

Yesterday I upgraded successfully from kubuntu 10.10 to 11.04 but when I start 'konsole'
the first thing is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lcr
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../crt1.o:    (.text+0x20): error: undefined reference to 'main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lcr
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../crt1.o:(.text+0x20): error: undefined reference to 'main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

what can I do to fix this, and what can I generally do to check if my Kubuntu installation is working?

Answer (score 2):

That message means that the `cr` library cannot be found.

Konsole shouldn't compile/ link anything when started, check your Konsole profile and the below files if exist:

```
.bashrc
.bash_profile
.profile
.bash_completion
.bash_aliases
```

If in doubt, post the files on http://paste.ubuntu.com so we can check these files.

If you've a legit need for linking files, you need to install the [libcr-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libcr-dev)[image: Install libcr-dev] package.

Comment: ok thanks it was caused by the line: $. /opt/openfoam171/etc/bashrc$ which I still had in .bashrc